# How to untangle graph as much as possible?

Tags: c#, graph, directed-graph, line-intersection

I wrote a short directed graph viewer that generates random nodes and random directed relationships between nodes and presents them on screen.

The nodes are currently positioned sequentially as a grid, and as one can notice, there's a lot of line intersections happening:

[image: Graph Viewer example]

I would like to reduce line intersections to make the graph look more appealing. There is no need to conform to the grid arrangement.

**How do I programmatically reposition the nodes to untangle the graph as much as possible?**

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work?

Comment: I have no idea how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Might be an idea to try on Maths.SE - it's essentially a topology problem first - when you have the algorithm, there are more people on here who can help you implement it

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. :)